# Error executing Ruby in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins ver. 1.537 on Win7 64.
I'm trying to run a Ruby script in Jenkins using the "Execute Ruby script" build function.
The command is C:/autotest/Ultrapos_FX2-3/lib/testout.rb.
The script I'm trying to run is a simple hello world type thing:-
begin
  puts 'TEST OUTPUT'
end

I can run this sucessfully from the command prompt, but Jenkins gives me the following error:-

```
Started by user anonymous

Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\ruby\workspace

[workspace] $ ruby -v C:\Users\ithomp\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson8549990801552818192.rb

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

C:/Users/ithomp/AppData/Local/Temp/hudson8549990801552818192.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected  tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input

C:/autotest/Ultrapos_FX2-3/lib/testout.rb

           ^

Build step 'Execute Ruby script' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems that Jenkins is not executing the script that I'm specifing and instead calling some temp file.
Any ideas as to what the issue is?.
Thanks.
Ian.

Comment: You can't call a Ruby script with the Ruby plugin.
You have to put the actual Ruby script content in the Jenkins plugin edit box or run the Ruby script as a batch file.

Comment: Also, in Windows I don't use the service as this is rubbish.
Instead I open a CMD and go to the Jenkins dir and run the war file and then leave the CMD window open.
e.g.
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins

java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9091